# How to set common header and footer using react native stack navigator and tab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native and I would like to set header as well the footer for all pages using stack and tab navigator. How to is it possible to have the header and the footer in the same file? 
The issue is if I return the header in a component, it returns the header alone and as same for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a component who represent your header. You should call it in all views of your application but its more properly than re-write the same header every where
I'm not sure if is the single option but it's the more simplest and not badless.